# How can I make consistent designs for similar items?

Tags: software-recommendation, page-layout, batch-processing

Salutations! I have remarkably little experience in graphic design, and I'm running into a tools problem; I am not sure what I can use to get the effect I want. To wit, I am working on mocking up some cards for use in an RPG. Right now, they look like this:

[image: blank RING card]

I would like to place some text in the white areas on this card. However, since there are quite a few different cards I am mocking up, I would like to do so in a ***consistent*** manner, preferably one that does not involve me having to count pixels to make sure each line of text is appropriately lined up. (If it was only the one card, I'd just wing it)

I've experience using Windows 7 Paint and Paint.net, but as near as I can determine, neither of these programs has the tools to handle such a case ***consistently***. Can anyone offer some advice or point me in the right direction?

P.S. I am aware that there is a "nuclear option", as it were, which would be to write a program and PDF-creation library to dynamically and generically create each card with the input text / colors (I've done something similar at my job), but I think that's overkill at this point, and I'd rather devote time to other things if I can help it.

Comment: My guess would be that Paint and Paint.net are not the correct tools to use. Things like Indesign, Illustrator, QuarkXPress, are designed to maintain a consistent layout through changes. Freeware/shareware apps such as Inkscape or Scribus would be better suited for layout than any "paint" application.

Comment: @Scott I understand that. As I mentioned, I have little experience with graphic design, and I'm interested in knowing what options are out there.

Comment: @Dominic That's just it; I don't know what software is out there! Do you have a suggestion as to what I might use?

Comment: By appropriately lined up you mean vertically centered? Or do you need the bottom box to fit to the text, like in Magic the gathering cards?

Comment: @Yisela The latter.

Comment: You can always use Magic Set Editor (magicseteditor.sourceforge.net), a program originally designed for creating fake (Magic: the Gathering) cards but is very flexible and has been used to create new card designs.  It allows for automatic wordwrapping and scores of other small features that would make your life easier, but you need to make the card template (which is a little time-consuming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've satisfactorily handled this now, and what I found worked best was to use CSS.

If you already have all the visual elements, it's a simple thing to render your image as a composite of HTML `<IMG>` and `<P>` elements. Use CSS to make sure all positions are relative within themselves, and you're good to go!

A little bit of Javascript and CSS can go a long way!

[image]             [image]

(PS: Next step -- figure out how to add black outlines so I don't have white text on a yellow background...)